# Error while obtaining start requests - Scrapy

Tags: python

I got an error when running Scrapy command.

2020-02-03 10:00:15 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/spawoz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)   File "/var/www/html/gemeinde/gemeindeParser/gemeindeParser/spiders/oberwil_news.py", line 43, in start_requests
    request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy_data[0] + ':' + proxy_data[1] TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**' 2020-02-03 10:00:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2020-02-03 10:00:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: {'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.005745,  'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 3, 4, 30, 15, 304823),  'log_count/ERROR': 1,  'log_count/INFO': 10,  'memusage/max': 75816960,  'memusage/startup': 75816960,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 3, 4, 30, 15, 299078)} 2020-02-03 10:00:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

---

My code is :

```
def start_requests(self):
    proxy_data = self.get_proxy();
    urls = [settings['TEST_NEWS_URL']]
    for url in urls:
        request =  scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy_data[0] + ':' + proxy_data[1]
        proxy_user_pass = settings['PROXY_USERNAME'] + ':' + settings['PROXY_PASSWORD']
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
        yield request
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what does 'proxy_data = self.get_proxy();' returns?

Comment: it returns null

Comment: I have one more question. I have a code:
eventTitle = item['title'].encode('utf-8')

But have an error occur. "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'"
How to resolve this

Comment: You are using wrong xpath/css for fetching the 'title' field. Try changing the selectors, often you see different DOM structure in browser and your crawler see a completely different thing. A good approach would be to either check response using "open_in_browser" or disable javascript and then view the code/html using inspect elements.